# ConcurrentHashMap retrieval operation does not take lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

as per Java docs

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update 
>         operations (including put and remove). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently   completed update operations holding upon their onset. For aggregate operations such as putAll  and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries

question : Suppose a thread t1 is updating a key-value pair(called x), and then other thread t2 comes and want to read x, will there be a copy c1 created of x at the onset of t2 and t2 will read from that copy c1

Answer (score 1):

> Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update
>   operations holding upon their onset

completed word is important here. Now your scenario is

```
 Suppose a thread t1 is updating a key-value pair(called x), and then other thread t2 comes and want to read x.
```

T2 will read  value updated by operation which has been completed not under process.In your scenario if update operation by thread t1 is not complete, t2 will not see the updated value. No copy is created. Its simple time funda. If by the time t2 thread read the x value and t2 update operation is complete, it will see the updated value otherwise not.

Comment: 'otherwise not.' -  from where t2 will see, as the old value does not exists anymore(it is in the process of update) when t2 arrived to read

Answer (score 1):

> > question : Suppose a thread t1 is updating a key-value pair(called x), and then other thread t2 comes and want to read x, will there be a copy c1 created of x at the onset of t2 and t2 will read from that copy c1

It depends. If the operation by T1 is **complete**, T2 will see that value. Otherwise, T2 will see the old value.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html:

> Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. For aggregate operations such as putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries

Comment: Otherwise, T2 will see the old value.  - but from where it will see, as the old value does not exists anymore(it is in the process of update)

Comment: @Naroji The old value will be there until T1 updates it. This is what the documentation means by "Complete". Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for inputs. If this is the case, then old_value replaced with new_value is a atomic operation(CAS), right ?

Comment: @JavaGeek yes, it *has* to be atomic and made visible to the other thread; otherwise this entire documentation would be useless